# Rviz: No tf data. Actual Error: Frame [map] does not exist

Tags: python, windows, ros2, gazebo-simu

I have followed this tutorial https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/ros2/nav2.html on how installing nav2 on windows.

However, although the map is loaded, I get a Global Status warn that the Frame map doesn't exist. Moreover 2D pose estimate doesn't to anything so I am not able to continue with the tutorial

[image]

And these are the traces I get in the cmd

```
c:\nav2_ws>ros2 launch turtlebot3_navigation2 navigation2.launch.py map:=c:\nav2_ws\map.yaml
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below C:\Users\yimmi\.ros\log\2022-04-02-16-43-57-695520-LAPTOP-9B37PMID-24652
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [map_server.EXE-1]: process started with pid [11332]
[INFO] [amcl.EXE-2]: process started with pid [2004]
[INFO] [lifecycle_manager.EXE-3]: process started with pid [7556]
[INFO] [controller_server.EXE-4]: process started with pid [11232]
[INFO] [planner_server.EXE-5]: process started with pid [24700]
[INFO] [recoveries_server.EXE-6]: process started with pid [4276]
[INFO] [bt_navigator.EXE-7]: process started with pid [19860]
[INFO] [waypoint_follower.EXE-8]: process started with pid [17164]
[INFO] [lifecycle_manager.EXE-9]: process started with pid [15680]
[INFO] [rviz2.EXE-10]: process started with pid [1688]
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.440874300] [planner_server]:
[planner_server.EXE-5]  planner_server lifecycle node launched.
[planner_server.EXE-5]  Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[planner_server.EXE-5]  See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.466464600] [planner_server]: Creating
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.565004600] [global_costmap.global_costmap]:
[planner_server.EXE-5]  global_costmap lifecycle node launched.
[planner_server.EXE-5]  Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[map_server.EXE-1] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading yaml file: c:\nav2_ws\map.yaml
[map_server.EXE-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: resolution: 0.05
[map_server.EXE-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[0]: -10
[map_server.EXE-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[1]: -10
[map_server.EXE-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[2]: 0
[map_server.EXE-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: free_thresh: 0.196
[map_server.EXE-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: occupied_thresh: 0.65
[map_server.EXE-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: mode: trinary
[map_server.EXE-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: negate: 0
[map_server.EXE-1] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading image_file: c:/nav2_ws/./map.pgm
[map_server.EXE-1] [DEBUG] [map_io]: Read map c:/nav2_ws/./map.pgm: 384 X 384 map @ 0.05 m/cell
[lifecycle_manager.EXE-3] [INFO] [1648910638.379500800] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Creating
[lifecycle_manager.EXE-3] [INFO] [1648910638.404704700] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: ←[34m←[1mCreating and initializing lifecycle service clients←[0m←[0m
[lifecycle_manager.EXE-3] [INFO] [1648910638.410535400] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: ←[34m←[1mStarting managed nodes bringup...←[0m←[0m
[lifecycle_manager.EXE-3] [INFO] [1648910638.410582700] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: ←[34m←[1mConfiguring map_server←[0m←[0m
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.611941400] [controller_server]:
[controller_server.EXE-4]       controller_server lifecycle node launched.
[controller_server.EXE-4]       Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[controller_server.EXE-4]       See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.691360600] [controller_server]: Creating controller server
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.708770800] [local_costmap.local_costmap]:
[controller_server.EXE-4]       local_costmap lifecycle node launched.
[controller_server.EXE-4]       Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[amcl.EXE-2] [INFO] [1648910638.653339000] [amcl]:
[amcl.EXE-2]    amcl lifecycle node launched.
[amcl.EXE-2]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[amcl.EXE-2]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[amcl.EXE-2] [INFO] [1648910638.653486800] [amcl]: Creating
[amcl.EXE-2] [INFO] [1648910638.695290200] [amcl]: Configuring
[amcl.EXE-2] [INFO] [1648910638.695386700] [amcl]: initTransforms
[amcl.EXE-2] [INFO] [1648910638.706869600] [amcl]: initPubSub
[amcl.EXE-2] [INFO] [1648910638.715456700] [amcl]: Subscribed to map topic.
[controller_server.EXE-4]       See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.717121200] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Creating Costmap
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.723281800] [controller_server]: Configuring controller interface
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.723490800] [controller_server]: Controller frequency set to 10.0000Hz
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.723543700] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Configuring
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.733655100] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.741401600] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Subscribing to the map topic (/map) with transient local durability
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.743598100] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Initialized plugin "static_layer"
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.743626300] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.744023700] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Subscribed to Topics: scan
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.747070300] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Initialized plugin "obstacle_layer"
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.747126000] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.748072400] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Initialized plugin "inflation_layer"
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.764481900] [controller_server]: Created progress_checker : progress_checker of type nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.768451200] [controller_server]: Created goal_checker : goal_checker of type nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.788025700] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: StaticLayer: Resizing static layer to 384 X 384 at 0.050000 m/pix
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.794341300] [controller_server]: Created controller : FollowPath of type dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.794793400] [controller_server]: Setting transform_tolerance to 0.200000
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.819797300] [controller_server]: Using critic "RotateToGoal" (dwb_critics::RotateToGoalCritic)
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.820448600] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.820683800] [controller_server]: Using critic "Oscillation" (dwb_critics::OscillationCritic)
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.821675300] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.821913800] [controller_server]: Using critic "BaseObstacle" (dwb_critics::BaseObstacleCritic)
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.822051700] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.822215900] [controller_server]: Using critic "GoalAlign" (dwb_critics::GoalAlignCritic)
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.822400600] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.822630500] [controller_server]: Using critic "PathAlign" (dwb_critics::PathAlignCritic)
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.823058200] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.823181800] [controller_server]: Using critic "PathDist" (dwb_critics::PathDistCritic)
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.823662200] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.823904900] [controller_server]: Using critic "GoalDist" (dwb_critics::GoalDistCritic)
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.824366200] [controller_server]: Critic plugin initialized
[lifecycle_manager.EXE-9] [INFO] [1648910638.534395200] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Creating
[lifecycle_manager.EXE-9] [INFO] [1648910638.623748400] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: ←[34m←[1mCreating and initializing lifecycle service clients←[0m←[0m
[lifecycle_manager.EXE-9] [INFO] [1648910638.635539700] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: ←[34m←[1mStarting managed nodes bringup...←[0m←[0m
[lifecycle_manager.EXE-9] [INFO] [1648910638.635620000] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: ←[34m←[1mConfiguring controller_server←[0m←[0m
[planner_server.EXE-5]  See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.576597200] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Creating Costmap
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.882739800] [planner_server]: Configuring
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.882799000] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Configuring
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.889232900] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.895895700] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Subscribing to the map topic (/map) with transient local durability
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.898262600] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "static_layer"
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.898391600] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.899082600] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Subscribed to Topics: scan
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.905113000] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "obstacle_layer"
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.905186100] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "voxel_layer"
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.905869000] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Subscribed to Topics: pointcloud
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.912604200] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "voxel_layer"
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.912684500] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.913827900] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "inflation_layer"
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.926877400] [planner_server]: Created global planner plugin GridBased of type nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner
[planner_server.EXE-5] [INFO] [1648910638.926921700] [planner_server]: Configuring plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
[recoveries_server.EXE-6] [INFO] [1648910638.672972100] [recoveries_server]:
[recoveries_server.EXE-6]       recoveries_server lifecycle node launched.
[recoveries_server.EXE-6]       Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[recoveries_server.EXE-6]       See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[recoveries_server.EXE-6] [INFO] [1648910638.975889500] [recoveries_server]: Configuring
[recoveries_server.EXE-6] [INFO] [1648910638.988092000] [recoveries_server]: Creating recovery plugin spin of type nav2_recoveries/Spin
[recoveries_server.EXE-6] [INFO] [1648910638.992397000] [recoveries_server]: Configuring spin
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910638.534239900] [bt_navigator]:
[bt_navigator.EXE-7]    bt_navigator lifecycle node launched.
[bt_navigator.EXE-7]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[bt_navigator.EXE-7]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910638.534339600] [bt_navigator]: Creating
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910639.053180700] [bt_navigator]: Configuring
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910639.109450200] [bt_navigator_rclcpp_node]: Waiting for "compute_path_to_pose" action server
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910639.109531100] [bt_navigator_rclcpp_node]: "ComputePathToPose" BtActionNode initialized
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910639.110524300] [bt_navigator_rclcpp_node]: Waiting for "global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap" service
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910639.110618500] [bt_navigator_rclcpp_node]: "ClearGlobalCostmap-Context" BtServiceNode initialized
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910639.113601200] [bt_navigator_rclcpp_node]: Waiting for "follow_path" action server
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910639.113680600] [bt_navigator_rclcpp_node]: "FollowPath" BtActionNode initialized
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910639.114314200] [bt_navigator_rclcpp_node]: Waiting for "local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap" service
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910639.114530600] [bt_navigator_rclcpp_node]: "ClearLocalCostmap-Context" BtServiceNode initialized
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910639.116083400] [bt_navigator_rclcpp_node]: Waiting for "local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap" service
[bt_navigator.EXE-7] [INFO] [1648910639.116223100] [bt_navigator_rclcpp_node]: "ClearLocalCostmap-Subtree" BtServiceNode initialized
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910638.824451700] [controller_server]: Controller Server has FollowPath  controllers available.
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910639.227356500] [controller_server]: Activating
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910639.227422800] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Activating
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910639.227447600] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Checking transform
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910639.227488600] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910639.729096600] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910640.233230600] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910640.740446100] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910641.228625700] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910641.728709600] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910642.234778900] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[rviz2.EXE-10] [INFO] [1648910642.967651500] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2.EXE-10] [INFO] [1648910642.969048300] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[rviz2.EXE-10] [INFO] [1648910643.026514700] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2.EXE-10] [WARN] [1648910643.559985200] [rcl.logging_rosout]: Publisher already registered for provided node name. If this is due to multiple nodes with the same name then all logs for that logger name will go out over the existing publisher. As soon as any node with that name is destructed it will unregister the publisher, preventing any further logs for that name from being published on the rosout topic.
[rviz2.EXE-10] [WARN] [1648910643.568240900] [rcl.logging_rosout]: Publisher already registered for provided node name. If this is due to multiple nodes with the same name then all logs for that logger name will go out over the existing publisher. As soon as any node with that name is destructed it will unregister the publisher, preventing any further logs for that name from being published on the rosout topic.
[rviz2.EXE-10] [WARN] [1648910643.574801400] [rcl.logging_rosout]: Publisher already registered for provided node name. If this is due to multiple nodes with the same name then all logs for that logger name will go out over the existing publisher. As soon as any node with that name is destructed it will unregister the publisher, preventing any further logs for that name from being published on the rosout topic.
[rviz2.EXE-10] [INFO] [1648910643.631234200] [rviz2]: Waiting for the lifecycle_manager_navigation/is_active service...
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910642.739862500] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[controller_server.EXE-4] [INFO] [1648910643.242255000] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
[rviz2.EXE-10] [INFO] [1648910643.631335400] [rviz2]: Sending lifecycle_manager_navigation/is_active request
[rviz2.EXE-10] [INFO] [1648910643.631412000] [rviz2]: Trying to create a map of size 384 x 384 using 1 swatches
[rviz2.EXE-10] [ERROR] [1648910643.636499900] [rviz2]: Vertex Program:rviz/glsl120/indexed_8bit_image.vert Fragment Program:rviz/glsl120/indexed_8bit_image.frag GLSL link result :
[rviz2.EXE-10] Validation failed! - Different sampler types for same sample texture unit in fragment shader.
[rviz2.EXE-10]
[rviz2.EXE-10] [ERROR] [1648910643.768634200] [rviz2]: Error prior to using GLSL Program Object : GL_INVALID_OPERATION
[rviz2.EXE-10] Validation successful.
[rviz2.EXE-10]
[rviz2.EXE-10] [ERROR] [1648910643.777334700] [rviz2]: Error prior to using GLSL Program Object : GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Does anyone know if a have something misconfigured? Maybe something related with the GLSL?

I am looking forward for your help as I need this working for my final project. Thank you in advance!

Comment: seems i am having the same issue as your. May I know if you know how to solve it? Thx

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/issues/925